# How to use Crystalize or Pointilize filter of jhlabs image library in Android?

Tags: android, image, filter

Can you reply example of Crystalize or Pointilize filter of jhlabs image library in Android? I did write code as my style, but it didn't work. :P

Following code is that I've written. it doesn't work. I don't know why the code doesn't work.

Can you tell me the reason?

```
    PointillizeFilter filter = new PointillizeFilter();
    filter.setEdgeColor(Color.BLACK);
    filter.setScale(10f);
    filter.setRandomness(0.1f);
    filter.setAmount(0.1f);
    filter.setFuzziness(0.1f);
    filter.setTurbulence(10f);
    filter.setGridType(PointillizeFilter.SQUARE);
    int[] src = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(artWork);
    filter.filter(src, width, height);
    Bitmap destImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the method `filter(src,width,height)` assign it to `src` then the code will work. Because this method returns the `IntArray` in JHLabs Library. So, the code will be:

```
PointillizeFilter filter = new PointillizeFilter();
filter.setEdgeColor(Color.BLACK);
filter.setScale(10f);
filter.setRandomness(0.1f);
filter.setAmount(0.1f);
filter.setFuzziness(0.1f);
filter.setTurbulence(10f);
filter.setGridType(PointillizeFilter.SQUARE);
int[] src = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(artWork);
src=filter.filter(src, width, height);
Bitmap destImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
PointillizeFilter pointillizeFilter = new PointillizeFilter();
pointillizeFilter.setEdgeThickness(0.45f);
pointillizeFilter.setFadeEdges(false);
pointillizeFilter.setEdgeColor(Color.GRAY);
pointillizeFilter.setFuzziness(1.0f);
int[] src47 = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(inter);
int width47 = inter.getWidth();
int height47 = inter.getHeight();
int[] dest47 = pointillizeFilter.filter(src47, width47, height47);
Bitmap destBitmap47 = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest47, width47, height47, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```